# How to make Contact Form 7 quiz field a placeholder

Tags: wordpress, placeholder, contact-form-7

I'm trying to add a "Quiz" field in Contact Form 7, but the question I have set is appearing above the field and cannot be seen against the background that the contact form is on. The rest of my fields are set as placeholders, is there any way to set the question of the Quiz field as a placeholder? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Amber

Answer (score -3, accepted):

From what I can gather without seeing you Contact Form 7 template code, is that you do not want to use the label within the page. If you remove the label content and within the 'quiz' field, you can add the question as a placeholder. An example of this would be:

```
[text* quiz-question placeholder "This would be your quiz question here?"]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: For those wondering why so many downvotes. Quiz field does NOT support the placeholder attribute. This is not a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

Contact form 7 does not have that capability. If you take a look at
https://github.com/thednp/contact-form-7-enhancements/blob/master/quiz.php
you can find code that has the functionallity so you can use placeholders.